# How to find minimum of BigDecimal field in collection with java streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to use **java streams** to iterate a **list** and find the `BigDecimal` minimum price. The following illustrates, but does not work (because `min()` cannot accept `BigDecimal`.

```
class Product {
    public BigDecimal price;
}

List<Product> products;
products.stream().min((Product) p -> p.price);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since `BigDecimal` already is `Comparable`, it is as simple as :

```
 BigDecimal min = products
        .stream()
        .map(Product::getPrice)
        .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        .orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Comment: Edited your answer. The name if the list is `producs` and not products.

Comment: `Product::getPrice` is invalid in this case, becase the OP does not have any setters and getters as seen in his `Product` class. He is accessing the `public BigDecimal price` field directly.

Comment: @AlexMamo yup, I assume he does

Comment: I have removed also the extra dot.

Comment: `min(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice))` is the right tool when you are actually interested in getting the `Product` with the minimum price. If you are only interested in the property itself (as `.map(Product::getPrice)` indicates), it’s more efficient to map before comparing, `.map(Product::getPrice) .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, as it will halve the number of `getPrice` invocations.

Comment: @Holger right again, what a terrible start of the day :| thank u

Comment: For most practical purposes, it doesn’t matter anyway, especially for a method like `getPrice` that’s supposed to be a trivial getter. It’s just that the right approach should become a habit, to make it also right when the property function is non-trivial.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a stream to find the minimum. Use `Collections.min`:

```
Collections.min(products, Comparator.comparing(p -> p.price));
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try :

```
Product minProductPrice = producs.stream()
        .min((o1, o2) -> o1.price.compareTo(o2.price)).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
products.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.price)).get();
```

`Comparator.comparing` method requires a Function that takes an input and returns a `Comparable`. This Comparable, in turn, is used by the comparing method to create a Comparator. The **`min`** method uses the Comparator to compare the elements in the stream.
The lambda expression `p->p.price` creates a Function that takes an `BigDecimal` and returns an [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) (which is a Comparable). Here, the lambda expression does not do much but in situations where you have a class that doesn't implement Comparable and you want to compare objects of that class using a property of that class that is Comparable, this is very useful.
The call to get() is required because `max(Comparator)` return an Optional object.

Comment: `.min(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.price))` will return the *`Product`* with the smallest price, not the price, so `.orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)` is not compatible to that. Besides that, `orElse` will *only* solve empty stream issue. If anything is `null`, the code will fail before ever encountering the `orElse`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Updated my answer. Thanks @Holger !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below as well,

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = products.stream()
            .map(d -> d.getPrice())
            .reduce(BigDecimal::min).get();

System.out.println(bigDecimal.longValueExact());
```